# Remove several items from observable array in an Angular 6 project with Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am having trouble understanding the concept of Observables in Angular (or Typescript) and I am looking for tips that help me understand better.

For instance, I have the following situation: I get data from a firestore db. I have processes and to each process, steps are associated in a separate collection per processid. It works fine so far to display the data.

Now when I delete a process item, I also want to delete the associated steps.

here is the code that I have so far:

the following method works:

```
  getProcessSteps(sid:string): Observable<Step[]> {
    return this.steps.pipe(map(steps => steps.filter(st => st.processid == sid)));
  }
```

this one works too (apart from the call to the deleteProcessSteps method):

```
  deleteProcess(id) {
    // delete associated steps
    this.deleteProcessSteps(id);

    this.processDoc = this.afs.doc<Process>(`processes/${id}`);
    this.processDoc.delete();
  }
```

Here is what I would like to understand:

```
 deleteProcessSteps(processid) {
   let stepdocs = this.getProcessSteps(processid);

   //Delete the steps
   for (let s of stepdocs) {         // <-- not working
     this.stepDoc = this.afs.doc<Step>(`steps/${s.id}`);
     this.processDoc.delete();
   }
 }
```

I get the error message: Type 'Observable' is not an array type or a string type. Although I don't find that very logical, I'll have to accept it.

Any advice on how to approach this would be extremely welcome !

Comment: you can do something like this,
this.getProcessSteps(processid).subscribe(data=>{
// put your logic here})

Comment: Since Observable is Async call, you should subscribe it and inside subscriber put your logic. this.getProcessSteps(processid);.subscribe((obj) => {
                console.log(obj);
            }, (error) => { console.log('error ' + error); }, () => {
   // success block
                // if you want to call another obserable or other method
            });

Comment: thanks! that helped in that I can achieve now what I wanted to achieve! for reasons of completeness, here is the outcome:
this.getProcessSteps(processid).subscribe(
      (obj) => {
        for(let s of obj) {
          this.afs.doc<Step>(`steps/${s.id}`).delete();
        }
      },
      (error) => {console.log(error)},
      () => {}
    );